# C++ Boost preprosessor equality testing

Tags: c++, boost, comparison

The equality testing of Boost PP looks like

```
# define NOT_EQUAL_I(x, y) CAT(NOT_EQUAL_CHECK_, NOT_EQUAL_ ## x(0, NOT_EQUAL_ ## y))
# define NOT_EQUAL_CHECK_NIL 1
# define NOT_EQUAL_CHECK_NOT_EQUAL_0(c, y) 0
# define NOT_EQUAL_CHECK_NOT_EQUAL_1(c, y) 0
# define NOT_EQUAL_CHECK_NOT_EQUAL_2(c, y) 0
# define NOT_EQUAL_CHECK_NOT_EQUAL_3(c, y) 0
# define NOT_EQUAL_0(c, y) IIF(c, NIL, y(1, NIL))
# define NOT_EQUAL_1(c, y) IIF(c, NIL, y(1, NIL))
# define NOT_EQUAL_2(c, y) IIF(c, NIL, y(1, NIL))
# define NOT_EQUAL_3(c, y) IIF(c, NIL, y(1, NIL))
```

which relies on the fact that macro expands for once in this situation.

However, another solution is easily thought, and seems to cost less (space):

```
#define EQ_0_0 ,
#define EQ_1_1 ,
#define EQ_2_2 ,
#define EQ_3_3 ,
#define SECOND(_,x,...) x
#define PARSE(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EQ(x,y) PARSE(SECOND PARSE() (0 EQ_##x##_##y 1, 0 ))
```

So why does Boost choose the former form rather than the latter one? What are the goods and bads of them?

Comment: those two are defining not the same symbols. And imho the first cost much less effort to read and understand (something that is more valuable than a couple of kb disc space or 1-2 minutes of typing)

Comment: @user463035818 They're just reversed output which doesn't matter much. I'd say the second one is easier read, but if they think the first one is and that's the reason then this queston is over

Comment: of course it matters, when both the call and the result are different then its not an alternative (maybe a "reverse alternative" ;). Anyhow, only the authors of the library can know why they made the decisions they made to arrive at that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost considered environment where `...` is not allowed(`BOOST_PP_VARIADICS`).

Comment: answering your own question is nothing to be sorry about :). You can even accept it and you should if it is answering the question. Nice that it turned out that the question has an answer